# In AWS, which type of IP to use if I want to keep a site private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

New to AWS and I wanted to host a website and share it with only a bunch of people and keep it private. I realized that each time I stop then start the EC2 instance, the public DNS and public IP are both reassigned a new one..

I read that you can allocate an elastic IP to the instance. Before I go ahead and do it, I want to get a sense of how secure this is. I assume whoever has the IP will be able to get to the site, will it be secure if the IP remains the same (elastic IPs persist until the instance is terminated, right?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot secure a site using a Elastic Ip address. If you want to keep the site private password protect it from the server side. Follow this link http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml

Comment: thanks, if I follow through, will the result be like this: each time I try to access the IP, it will ask for a username and password in a pop-up menu?

Comment: Yes it will ask for use name and password each time.

Comment: This is HTTP Basic Authentication, which isn't really secure by itself. You also need to use (and force) https connections with strong encryption ciphers. That of course requires you to obtain and properly install an SSL certificate. I don't see any of that mentioned on the linked page other than the "word of caution" at the end that mentions that this method of authentication shouldn't be used for anything serious or important.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding some sort of secure login functionality, you should look into using [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) to limit who can access your site.

Relying on any sort of IP address obscurity like you are suggesting is **NOT** secure.

Comment: I will look into security groups. Does that apply to a regular EC2 instance or it only applies to AWS VPC? The link you gave is part of the VPC document.

Comment: All EC2 instances belong to a security group. Although, if you created your AWS account in the last few years you will be using a VPC.